# mIRC parsing a name

Tags: script, mirc, parsing

Asked originally: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419961/mirc-parsing-for-a-name

So I've been getting a bothersome someone who keeps using my nickname. What I want to be able to do is perform the following command every time someone with exactly my nickname (let's say UserName) joins the channel I currently reside in:

/msg NickServ ghost UserName n0ideaHwatPassIs?

n0ideaHwatPassIs? is a sample password for our sample registered user of UserName

This sort of script would have to be able to check (in more or less real-time) if a separate user changed his/her nick to said UserName as well. If someone would be so kind as to help me with my dilemma by either pointing me to the proper documentation or working out such a script (no idea if this is as cut-and-dry as I imagined it would be at first) for me?

Comment: i have already answered your question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419961/mirc-parsing-for-a-name/23420303#23420303 check it there

Answer (score 0):

You can register and then set NickServ to enforce a name change if someone logs in with that name.

1) Register your nick.

`/msg nickserv register <password> <email>`

You will receive an email with a password to confirm the registration process.

2) To avoid other users using your nickname.

`/msg NickServ set enforce on`

If someone try to use your nickname, this person will have their nickname changed.

3) To identify yourself as the owner of the nick run this when you connect.

`/msg nickserv identify <password>`

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally use `/msg nickserv set kill quick` option. this tells nickserv when a user comes on and uses "your" nick.. they will only have 20 secs to try and identify to your nick after which time the server will force change the user to a random nick